# Django Compressor: multiple errors when ran but working fine

Tags: python, django, django-compressor

I have installed `django-compressor==2.4.1` on my `Django==2.2.28` project.

As on the documentation, I installed it by putting `compressor` in my INSTALLED_APPS and added `'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder'` to my STATICFILES_FINDERS.

by now I am just trying it and using it on my `base.html` on the following:

```
        {% compress css %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/survey.css' %}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Roboto.css' %}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/AdminLTE.min.css' %}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}"/>
        {% endcompress %}
```

And I enabled the following settings:

```
# Django Compressor
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True
COMPRESS_OFFLINE_TIMEOUT = 31536000  # 1 year in seconds
```

but when I run `manage.py compress` the console is filled with errors, all about files that seem to be in the very same `django-compressor` folder. The compressed file gets made anyway and everything works fine.

Here is the full output: https://pastebin.com/20kuHKLw

Can anyone explain what is happening?